# Witcher 2 missing library libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, games, shared-library

The events that led to this situation are as follows:

1. I tried to run The Wither 2 on Linux from GoG.com and installed the dependencies 
   (http://www.gog.com/game/the_witcher_2) using aptitude.
2. I rebooted and it gets to the Ubuntu GNOME logo but not further than that, so I went to command line did `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get dist-upgrade`.
3. I then removed the packages again and did `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get dist-upgrade` `apt-get autoclean` `apt-get autoremove` again.
4. It still did not work so I re-installed gnome shell and steam and after a while the machine boots again and everything seems to work.
5. So I am back at the beginning: When I try to run the `start.sh` file to start Witcher 2 I get an error saying there is no `libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0` file

I am using a GTX 750 with the drivers given by the additional drivers menu in Ubuntu.
After this experience I rather ask other people for help. I do not know how to install this package because there does not seem to be such a package.
EDIT: I searched for libgtk-x11-2.0.so and it found it in "/home/saur/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" and in "/home/saur/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/"

Comment: `apt-file search libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0` gives me the package `libgtk2.0-0`. Do you have that installed? Does that file or a similar one exist on your system (`locate -b libgtk-x11-2.0.so\*`)? Please [edit] your question to add additional info.

Comment: I have that file installed, but still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I know that it's a little bit late but, if it can be useful for someone else, I had the same issue, and in my case it was due to my ubuntu x64 version. I've just to install the package for i386 architecture and it was done.

So just install all packages missing with ":i386" at the end of each apt-get install command (example : sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386).

Answer (score 0):

I've tested on Ubuntu 14.04.2 (the same that cannot run the game obtained from GOG) via Steam and the game runs perfectly fine.

Also, consider updating your system, as when I wrote to GOG about why this happens their response was, that this is a common issue to anyone running 14.04.2 due to how the distro is packaged and it containing Utopic graphics packages. There are limitations due to which you simply cannot install the required libraries.

The solution is either to downgrade to 14.04 or upgrade to the very latest regardless of what the GOG website says in terms of support.

Read the full reply here:

[image: Reply from GOG]